# Por que se cumple esta condicion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operador

Hola devs tengo esta condicion y aun no entiendo por que se cumple.

- la variable act_day me almacena el dia actual
- la variable last_day me almacena el ultimo dia del mes

todo esto gracias al objeto Time propio del lenguaje.

```
desc "Tarea Prueba"
        task :prueba => :environment do
            
            act_day = Time.current.day
            last_day = Time.current.end_of_month.day

            if act_day == 15 || last_day
                puts "La tarea se puede ejecutar"
            else
                puts "Todavia no"
            end
        end
```

la condicion no se deberia cumplir ya que no estoy en el dia '15' ni estoy en el ultimo del mes.

Aun asi la condicion se cumple y no se por que.

Comment: Ese `or` está bien planteado? No tengo idea de RoR y la segunda condición tiene `last_day` pero no lo compara con nada. En otros lenguajes, eso va a validar si esa variable está inicializada o no para decir true o false... la otra opción es que estés escribiendo muy coloquial y supongas que estás comparando con act_day pero NO. Explícitamente cada expresión lógica debe ir completa (no es lenguaje natural)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a Alfabravo por iluminarme, la segunda variable no se estaba comparando con nada por eso siempre me devolvía true.

```
if act_day == 15 || last_day == act_day
                puts "La tarea se puede ejecutar"
            else
                puts "Todavia no"
            end
```

se debía comparar con el día actual.